# Restart VPN service when NetworkManager is restarted

Tags: networkmanager, systemctl, wireguard

I need to manually restart my VPN service (`wg-quick@mullvad-sg2`) after restarting `NetworkManager` in order to have DNS lookups work correctly.

How can I have restarting `NetworkManager` also restart my VPN service?

Comment: ... or, just don't restart NetworkManager. There are few reasons why NetworkManager should be restarted. if you are doing that regularly, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: My root problem was determined to be DNS not working with Wireguard.  Manually restarting `wg-quick@mullvad-sg2` worked, but strangely not when using the automated answer below.

The broken DNS problem and solution are described [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/WireGuard#Broken_DNS_resolution).

Comment: @thaller Whats the idomatic cli way to say "disconnect / reconnect the current wifi hotspot"?

Comment: `nmcli connection down "$PROFILE"` to disconnect a profile. `nmcli connection up "$PROFILE"` to connect a profile. There is also `nmcli device down "$DEVICE"` and `nmcli device up "$DEVICE"`, but it seems usually preferably to activate/deactivate the profile.

Answer (score 1):

Identify the service that needs to restart with `NetworkManager` --  in this case, it's `wg-quick@`.

Edit the `override.conf` for `wg-quick@` by typing:

`sudo systemctl edit wg-quick@`

Add the following:

```
[Unit]
# Restart / Stop with NetworkManager
PartOf=NetworkManager.service

# Wait until network is really up before trying to have Wireguard connect
# https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/NetworkTarget/
Requires=NetworkManager-wait-online.service
After=NetworkManager-wait-online.service
```

Comment: This solves the question as stated, but see the comment under the question for the root cause and actual solution.